# Declaring an instance of Eq (Tree a) where two trees are equal if they have the same elements

Tags: haskell, types, tree

I'm trying to create an instance of Eq (Tree a) for my tree datatype in Haskell, so that two trees are equal if they have the same elements. So I have a method that turns my tree into a list (flatten), and then I compare the sorted lists.
But I'm getting errors like there is no instance for (Ord a) when I sort my list, or (Eq a) when I == my two lists.

```
import Data.List as L    
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)

instance Eq (Tree a) where     
 (==) t1 t2 = L.sort(flatten t1) == L.sort(flatten t2)

flatten :: Tree a -> [a]    
flatten EmptyTree = []    
faltten (Node x1 y x2) = [y] ++ (flatten x1) ++ (flatten x2)
```

I don't know why this refuses to compile. I used a method I have that makes a tree from a list and flattening that tree returns the original list, so I know flatten is working properly. I'm assuming it's complaining about not knowing if the contents of the list are Ord or Eq, but I don't know how to fix this. Adding

```
 (Ord a, Eq a) =>
```

to the flatten signature didn't do it.

Comment: Does your tree have any ordering invariants? Is it, for example, a search tree? That would let you test for equality much more efficiently.

Comment: No it's just a very simple tree, it's just a few exercices to teach us to create instances.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is *not* with `flatten`: `flatten` does not need the elements to be orderable, it just produces a list of the elements.

The problem is that you use [**`sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort) in your implementation of `(==)`, and `sort` thus needs the elements in the list to be of a type that is an instance of the `Ord` typeclass.

The type of the elements also needs to be a member of the `Eq` typeclass, since you then call `(==)` on the lists. But since `Ord` implies `Eq`, that is not really a problem here.

We thus need to add these type constraints to the `instance` declaration:

```
instance Ord a => Eq (Tree a) where     
 (==) t1 t2 = L.sort(flatten t1) == L.sort(flatten t2)
```

So here we can only check if two trees are equal, given the trees contain elements of a type that is an instance of the `Ord` typeclass.